# What is new in ASP.NET MVC 5.1 apart from those mentioned in Release Notes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

What are new features in ASP.NET MVC 5.1 apart from those mentioned in [Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes):

1. Attribute routing improvements
2. Bootstrap support for editor templates
3. Enum support in views
4. Unobtrusive validation for MinLength/MaxLength Attributes
5. Supporting the ‘this’ context in Unobtrusive Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any beyond the [bug fixes mentioned](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?keyword=&status=Closed&type=All&priority=All&release=v5.1%20Preview%7Cv5.1%20RTM&assignedTo=All&component=MVC&sortField=AssignedTo&sortDirection=Ascending&page=0&reasonClosed=Fixed) in the Release Notes you linked to.